# What does *tuple and **dict mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, namedtuple, iterable-unpacking

As mentioned in PythonCookbook, `*` can be added before a tuple. What does `*` mean here?

> Chapter 1.18. Mapping Names to Sequence Elements:
>
> ```
> from collections import namedtuple
> Stock = namedtuple('Stock', ['name', 'shares', 'price'])
> s = Stock(*rec) 
> # here rec is an ordinary tuple, for example: rec = ('ACME', 100, 123.45)
> ```

In the same section, `**dict` presents:

> ```
> from collections import namedtuple
> Stock = namedtuple('Stock', ['name', 'shares', 'price', 'date', 'time'])
> # Create a prototype instance
> stock_prototype = Stock('', 0, 0.0, None, None)
> # Function to convert a dictionary to a Stock
> def dict_to_stock(s):
>     return stock_prototype._replace(**s)
> ```

What is `**`'s function here?

Comment: Please read [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). ([Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists))

Comment: And it's not `**tuple` but `**dictionary`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters SORRY for that, I will try to fix it.

Comment: No problem, just pointing to a misunderstanding on your part.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is not a duplicate question if you starting with the language. For me this question gave a different perspective then *arg and **kwargs.

Comment: @AnuragJain: How is it different? They both ask what `*` and `**` mean in the context of a function call. Being a duplicate is not merely asking a slightly different question, it has to be a question that would not lead to effectively identical answers. In both questions, the answer needed explains the same things. The answer here adds information not requested by the person who asked the question, which is fine, but the information requested here is a subset of what the other question requested. This is a great breadcrumb, but it's still a duplicate.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

## In a function call

`*t` means "treat the elements of this iterable as positional arguments to this function call."

```
def foo(x, y):
    print(x, y)

>>> t = (1, 2)
>>> foo(*t)
1 2
```

Since v3.5, you can also do this in a list/tuple/set literals:

```
>>> [1, *(2, 3), 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`**d` means "treat the key-value pairs in the dictionary as additional named arguments to this function call."

```
def foo(x, y):
    print(x, y)

>>> d = {'x':1, 'y':2}
>>> foo(**d)
1 2
```

Since v3.5, you can also do this in a dictionary literals:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> {'b': 2, **d}
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
```

## In a function signature

`*t` means "take all additional positional arguments to this function and pack them into this parameter as a tuple."

```
def foo(*t):
    print(t)

>>> foo(1, 2)
(1, 2)
```

`**d` means "take all additional named arguments to this function and insert them into this parameter as dictionary entries."

```
def foo(**d):
    print(d)

>>> foo(x=1, y=2)
{'y': 2, 'x': 1}
```

## In assignments and `for` loops

`*x` means "consume additional elements in the right hand side", but it doesn't have to be the last item. Note that `x` will always be a list:

```
>>> x, *xs = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> x
1
>>> xs
[2, 3, 4]

>>> *xs, x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> xs
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x
4

>>> x, *xs, y = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> x
1
>>> xs
[2, 3]
>>> y
4

>>> for (x, *y, z) in [ (1, 2, 3, 4) ]: print(x, y, z)
...
1 [2, 3] 4
```

---

Note that parameters that appear after the starred parameter (the one marked `*`) are keyword-only:

```
def f(a, *, b): ...

f(1, b=2)  # fine
f(1, 2)    # error: b is keyword-only
```

Python3.8 added [positional-only parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters), meaning parameters that cannot be used as keyword arguments. They appear before a `/` (a pun on `*` preceding keyword-only args).

```
def f(a, /, p, *, k): ...

f(  1,   2, k=3)  # fine
f(  1, p=2, k=3)  # fine
f(a=1, p=2, k=3)  # error: a is positional-only
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'll just add keyword `operator` to make this answer easier to find when somebody searches for `python operator **` expecting `*` or `**` this is called operator in this context.

Comment: Great answer. Just to add that in the case of "In a function signature" the common idiom is to use *args for positional arguments and **kwargs for keyword arguments.

Comment: @GuzmanOjero this is true, but only if there is no meaningful alternative.