# Create one dictionary for each combination of list-values in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
my_dict = {"A":0, "B":[1,2], "C":3}
```

I am trying to split this into a list of 2 dictionaries that encompass each possible value. For example:

```
#Desired result
[{"A":0, "B":1, "C":3}, {"A":0, "B":2, "C":3}]
```

I am able to get a list of each needed dictionary, in hopes I can then loop through the list and merge dictionaries using `update()`. This will overwrite the key `"B"`and only create a single dict.

Here is what I have done:

```
dict_list = []
my_dict = {"A":0, "B":[1,2], "C":3}

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if type(v) == list:
        for i in v:
            dict1 = {k:i}
            dict_list.append(dict1)
    if type(v) != list:
        dict2 = {k:v}
        dict_list.append(dict2)

new_dict = {}
for d in dict_list:
    new_dict.update(d)

print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'A':0, 'B':2, 'C':3}
```

This is overwriting the key `'B'` and creating only one dictionary based on the last value.

Comment: you need to create a `defaultdict(list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy if your dict can have only one list.

```
>>> my_dict = {"A":0, "B":[1,2], "C":3}
>>> k, lst = next((k, v) for k, v in my_dict.items() if isinstance(v, list))
>>> [{**my_dict, k:x} for x in lst]
[{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 3}, {'A': 0, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}]
```

It's a bit trickier if your dict can have multiple lists.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> 
>>> my_dict = {"A":0, "B":[1,2], "C":[3, 4]}
>>> lists_kv = ([(k, x) for x in v] for k, v in my_dict.items() if isinstance(v, list))
>>> [{**my_dict, **dict(x)} for x in product(*lists_kv)]
[{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 3},
 {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 4},
 {'A': 0, 'B': 2, 'C': 3},
 {'A': 0, 'B': 2, 'C': 4}]
```

Comment: Marked this as the correct answer as it is absolutely doing what I needed it to do, so thank you. Could you explain what [{**my_dict, k:x} for x in lst] is actually doing?  I am trying to step through but the **my_dict portion is throwing me off.

Comment: Think I answered my own question. For anyone wondering see [What does **dict mean in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809112/what-does-tuple-and-dict-means-in-python)

Comment: @EricT see also [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/3620003)