# Is there a better way? string formatting using a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, formatting

Is there a better way of doing the following..

```
    template = """
This goes here {Item1},,, and here {Item2}
   and here {Item3}
"""

mydict = {'Item1':'Cat', 
          'Item2':'Dog', 
          'Item3':'Hamster', 
          'Item4':'Donkey'
         }

result = template.format(Item1=mydict['Item1'], Item2=mydict['Item2'], Item3=mydict['Item3'])
```

The main thing being that the place holders in the format string are named exactly the same as the key values in the dictionary.

BUT The dictionary may contain more key values than there are place holders. The place holders will ALWAYS be a subset of the dictionary

I have tried

```
template.format(**mydict)
```

but that gives a KeyError exception. I had hoped that silently catching that exception would work but it doesn't

My gut feeling is that there must be a more pythonic way to do this other than the long-hand way above.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a string using a dictionary in python-3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952344/how-do-i-format-a-string-using-a-dictionary-in-python-3-x)

Comment: `result = template.format(**mydict)`  ["`**mydict` means "treat the key-value pairs in the dictionary as additional named arguments to this function call.""](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21809162/1248974)

Comment: Thank you both. If the dictionary has more keys than there are place holders in the format string, will **mydict still work?

Comment: @TheWelshDragon try it and see? .. just tried it myself and indeed `**mydict` will still properly fill the output if there are less placeholders than keys, the output is only the first two values: `This goes here Cat,,, and here Dog`

Comment: Can you please include show us how `template.format(**mydict)` gives a KeyError exception?